# List of Methods required to be run in JavaFX Application Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I'm currently trying to develop an JavaFX Application (Game). In order to keep the application run smoothly, I try to lay off as much of the program logic into a separate thread. However, I often stumble into the problem that some JAVAFX API Calls require to be run in JFX Application thread. E.g. creating a set of rectangles and coloring it, can be done in a thread - while adding them to a "Group", calling .doLayout() and .applycss() requires JFX Appl. thread.
I also realized that ".play()" a transition is also required to be run in JFX Application thread.

The problem is - if you are not executing it in the correct thread - an "array out of bounds" exception may occur randomly within JFX which does not point you to the root cause. It always hard to determine whether the program and graphic logic can be offloaded to a thread or is required to be run in JFX Application Thread.

Does anybody know a list of JavaFX method calls which require to be run under JFX Application Thread?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [`Application` class documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/application/Application.html) (and this is also specified in other places in the JavaFX documentation):

> Creation of JavaFX Scene and Stage objects as well as modification of scene graph operations to live objects (those objects already attached to a scene) must be done on the JavaFX application thread.

So you can create new nodes (e.g. rectangles) on a background thread, and you can modify their properties (e.g. "color them") on a background thread as long as they have not been attached to a scene. Once the node is attached to a scene, any modification of the node must occur on the FX Application Thread.

If a pane or group is attached to a scene, then calling `getChildren().add(...)` modifies that pane/group, so it must be performed on the FX Application Thread. The other examples you cite (`layout()` and `applyCSS()`) only make sense if the relevant node is attached to a scene anyway.

Comment: Thank you for that. Would this also mean that e.g. Node.getBoundsInParent().getHeight() needs to be run in JFX appl thread?

Comment: @Defarine That question ("Can you access 'live' node properties, if you are not modifying them, from a background thread?") is actually not explicitly answered by any documentation I've seen. I think it is fair to assume, however, that if there is no synchronization that makes it thread-safe to modify a property then there is no synchronization to safely access it either, so I would interpret the rules as "you should only access 'live' nodes from the FX Application Thread".

Comment: @Defarine TBH it's pretty hard for me to see any real use case where you would want to access the height of a node from a background thread anyway.