# Determine creation thread of new Nodes in JavaFX

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

this is a follow on question to my previous question:
[List of Methods required to be run in JavaFX Application Thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46956203/list-of-methods-required-to-be-run-in-javafx-application-thread)

Consider I have a Borderpane class with an init() method which makes the skinning and styles, e.g.:

```
public class DraggableLabel extends BorderPane {
  public void init()
  {
     Label mainLabel = new Label("Hello");
     mainLabel.setStyle(....);
     this.setCenter(mainLabel);
  }

  ....
}
```

I'm still stuggling with the problem that it may happen, that the init() method is not called via JAVAFX Application Thread. This may be no problem if the BorderPane is not yet attached to a scene. However, I cannot assure that the programmer has already attached it to the scene before calling init().

How can I check that this Borderpane has not yet been attached to a scene? (e.g. throw an exception). Would it help to set the Borderpane to "setVisible(false)" in constructor and only set it to setVisible(true) at the very end of the init() method?

Thanks!

Comment: `if (getScene() == null)` will check if it has been added to a scene, though of course if you are not on the FX Application thread you have a race condition between setting the scene and executing the ensuing code anyway. Is it not possible to put this code in a constructor (in which case you can be assured it has not yet been added to a scene)?

Comment: And, no, changing the visibility will make no difference. (And anyway, if you're not on the FX Application Thread and the pane is attached to a scene, changing the visibility would also violate the threading rules...)